# xero's PayRun Api always throw PayRunPeriodEndDate validation error

Tags: laravel, xero-api

I am trying to create pay run on xero, but it always gives me the same error.

```
The PayRunPeriodEndDate must be after the calendar start date
```

I put `PayRunPeriodEndDate` date after the calendar start date, but still it give the same problem.
i am on api explorer.
my payload is

```
[ { "PayrollCalendarID": "d99590f1-670d-4bc1-947c-a6cac36e31d2", "PayRunPeriodStartDate": "/Date(1689552000+0000)/", "PayRunPeriodEndDate": "/Date(1689552000+0000)/", "PayRunStatus": "POSTED", "PaymentDate": "/Date(1689984000000+0000)/" } ]
```

while calendar start date is `"StartDate":"\/Date(1689379200000+0000)\/"`
Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks.